# SherlockFragmentActivity java.lang.NoSuchFieldError when setting content view at the beginning

Tags: android, exception, view, actionbarsherlock, layout-inflater

when starting the activity, I'm retrieving the following error:

```
02-14 09:51:30.898: V/ViolazioniActivity(7510): onCreate before 2130903076
02-14 09:51:30.913: D/dalvikvm(7510): DexOpt: couldn't find static field Lit/helian/violazioni/R$id;.btn1
02-14 09:51:30.913: W/dalvikvm(7510): VFY: unable to resolve static field 6831 (btn1) in Lit/helian/violazioni/R$id;
02-14 09:51:30.913: D/dalvikvm(7510): VFY: replacing opcode 0x60 at 0x0015
02-14 09:51:30.913: D/dalvikvm(7510): DexOpt: couldn't find static field Lit/helian/violazioni/R$id;.btn2
02-14 09:51:30.913: I/dalvikvm(7510): DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x1ab0 at 0x30 in Lit/helian/violazioni/fe/ui/ViolazioniDashboardFragment;.onCreateView
    02-13 18:14:32.565: E/AndroidRuntime(26290): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    02-13 18:14:32.565: E/AndroidRuntime(26290): java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: it.helian.violazioni.R$id.btn1
    02-13 18:14:32.565: E/AndroidRuntime(26290):    at it.helian.violazioni.fe.ui.ViolazioniDashboardFragment.onCreateView(ViolazioniDashboardFragment.java:38)
    02-13 18:14:32.565: E/AndroidRuntime(26290):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:846)
    02-13 18:14:32.565: E/AndroidRuntime(26290):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1061)
    02-13 18:14:32.565: E/AndroidRuntime(26290):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1160)
    02-13 18:14:32.565: E/AndroidRuntime(26290):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:272)
    02-13 18:14:32.565: E/AndroidRuntime(26290):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:669)
```

Main activity

```
    package it.helian.violazioni.be.activity;

import it.helian.violazioni.R;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;
import com.googlecode.androidannotations.annotations.EActivity;

//@EActivity(resName="activity_violazioni")
@EActivity
public class ViolazioniActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

    public static final String TAG = "ViolazioniActivity";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.v(TAG, "onCreate before " + R.layout.activity_violazioni);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_violazioni);
        Log.v(TAG, "onCreate after");
    }
}
```

R.layout.activity_violazioni

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/home_root"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_dashboardz"
    android:name="it.helian.violazioni.fe.ui.ViolazioniDashboardFragment"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

it.helian.violazioni.fe.ui.ViolazioniDashboardFragment

```
public class ViolazioniDashboardFragment extends SherlockFragment {
        @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        System.out.println("Check 2a");
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_menu, container);
        System.out.println("Check 2b");
        btn1 = (MainButton) root.findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        System.out.println("Check 3");
        btn1.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        fireTrackerEvent(EVENT_CLICK_CLASSICA);
                    }

                });

        btn2 =(MainButton) root.findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        btn2.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        fireTrackerEvent(EVENT_CLICK_CLASSICA_ANPR);
                    }
                });
}
```

main_menu.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="1dp"
android:weightSum="101" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="10" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="27"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="10" >

    <it.helian.violazioni.fe.ui.MainButton
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="5" />

    <it.helian.violazioni.fe.ui.MainButton
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="5" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="10" />
```

If you need further details, just write them down, I will try to help you as much as possible!

Thank you in advance

Regards,

Luca

Comment: Tried so many times... but it doesn't work

Comment: Also make sure you've imported the `R` class from your app and **not** `android.R` class.

Comment: Did you checked the `R` class to see if the field btn1 exists?

Comment: Yes, still checked. I have read all the similar articles like that, without any positive result, unfortunetly... It cannot access to R.id.btn1. Commenting that lines the layout (blank) is opened with no exception.

I have added somelines to the first code snippet (the exception thrown), maybe it can be usefull for you...

Comment: Yes it is:

        public static int btn1=0x7f060030;
        public static int btn2=0x7f060031;

Comment: Can you try renaming the layouts files and the ids used in the activity and fragments to something else, cleaning your project and then run it again? See how it goes.

Comment: @Luksprog I'm sorry but neither with that changes it works, same exception as in the answer